formula to show total number of "Y" out of total entered Google Sheets?
I am wanting to figure out a formula to show the total of "Y" over the total amount entered.
My sheet has a column where I am selecting "Y" or "NO".
At the top of the page I have a cell finding the amount of how many "Y" were entered which is and formatted the number to be a percent:
=COUNTIF(H10:H1067,"Y")/COUNTA(H10:H1067)
My issue is I can't figure out how to get it to display as # of "Y" / total amount.
For example:
Let's say there is 50 entries and only 6 are "Y". so it would display 6/50
Thanks in advance.

This concatenate every part as a string using the concat function =CONCAT(COUNTIF(H10:H1067,"Y"), CONCAT("/", COUNTA(H10:H1067)))

Throwing an error: Wrong number of arguments to CONCAT. Expected 2 arguments, but got 3 arguments.

Double CONCAT it is then =CONCAT(COUNTIF(H10:H1067,"Y"), CONCAT("/", COUNTA(H10:H1067))

I forgot a closing parentheses at the end of the formula, but other than that it works on my side

That latest one worked thanks so much!

You can also use a simpler version that uses &: =COUNTIF(H10:H167,"Y")&"/"&COUNTA(H10:H167)
